# Получить массив элемнтов у которых атрибут равен значению

Tags: javascript, jquery

Бодрого вечера, есть список

```
<li value="1" par="0">1</li>
<li value="2" par="1"> -- 2</li>
<li value="3" par="2"> -- -- 3</li>
```

При нажатии на первый элемент нужно достать массив элементов у которых `par = "1"`  скрыть их и их дочек, тоже в цикле, рекурсивная функция вроде называется. Как это сделать ?

В основном не понятно только как достать массив, с которым потом работать

Comment: Достать массив можно так: $('li[par=' + val + ']')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(e => {
  $('ul').on('click', '[par]', function(e){
    // Вот элемент, у которого атрибут par равен значению value у кликнутого li
    let child = $(`[par="${this.value}"]`);
    
    child.css({color: 'red'});
  });
});
```

```css
li{cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li value="1" par="0">1</li>
  <li value="2" par="1">-- 2</li>
  <li value="3" par="2">-- -- 3</li>
</ul>
```